# MySql, exclude a subset with association table

Tags: mysql, sql

Have 2 tables. Table "students" with column "student_id" and "score". Association table "class_student" with column "class_id" and "student_id". How to list class_ids that all student scores of the class are over 80. Which means if the class has any student score less than 80 then the class won't be listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `min()`for this purpose:

```
select cs.class_id
from class_student cs join
     students s
     on s.student_id = cs.student_id
group by cs.class_id
having min(s.score) >= 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the classes and take only those groups having no record with your specified condition

```
select cs.class_id
from class_student cs
join students s on s.student_id = cs.student_id
group by cs.class_id
having sum(s.score < 80) = 0
```